# How do I track traffic sources and conversions for my extension on the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-ads-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need help with something important. I made a Chrome extension, and lots of people are downloading it from different places like my website, YouTube, and Google Ads. But I'm trying to find out how many people are downloading it specifically because of the Google Ads I put up.

I'm running ads on Google to promote my extension, and I want to see if they're working well. The problem is, when people download the extension from the Chrome store, I can't able to track which source user download and that's why i can't able to count ROI etc for my ads spent?

i need solution for it!